# Solidity hard-coding initial values for array of uint256 values fails

Tags: arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I’m trying to create an array of 10 integers (`uint256`) and hard-code their initial starting values - but I keep getting the following error (which weirdly talks about `uint16`, even though I specifically ask for `uint256`):

```
TypeError: Type uint16[10] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] memory.
```

Here’s my code:

```
uint256 memory myNumbersArray = new uint256[](10);
myNumbersArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
```

I also tried it this way:

```
uint256[10] memory myNumbersArray;
myNumbersArray = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];
```

Same results.

(I think I also tried to do the whole thing in one line.)

Am I getting this error because the actual values I’m assigning are so small that they don’t need to be of type `uint256`?
I need to know this because the **future** values that this array is supposed to hold will absolutely be big enough to merit being of type `uint256`.

How do I solve this?
The starting values I'm assigning aren't filler/dummy values - they're exactly what I need them to be. So it’s not as if I can just plug in a bunch of crazy high numbers for no reason just to pass compilation or something.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast the first value to be of type uint256 and the whole array will be of that type.

```
uint256[10] memory myNumbersArray;
myNumbersArray = [uint256(0), 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];
```